# How to send touch event in Geckofx?

Tags: c#, geckofx

I use Geckofx in my program.I just want to send touch event (like touchstart , touchmove , touchend) to the document of Geckobrowser.I had try to add the method in "WindowUtils.cs" of "Gecko-core.dll" ,like that:

```
public Boolean SendTouchEvent(string aType, uint[] aIdentifiers, int[] aXs, int[] aYs, uint[] aRxs, uint[] aRys, float[] aRotationAngles, float[] aForces, uint count, int aModifiers, bool aIgnoreRootScrollFrame)
{
    using (nsAString type = new nsAString(aType))
    {
        return _windowUtils.Instance.SendTouchEvent(type, aIdentifiers, aXs, aYs, aRxs, aRys, aRotationAngles, aForces, count, aModifiers, aIgnoreRootScrollFrame);
    }
}
```

This method uses the the method "SendTouchEvent" in "nsIDOMWindowUtils.cs", like that :

```
/// <summary>
    ///Synthesize a touch event. The event types supported are:
    /// touchstart, touchend, touchmove, and touchcancel
    ///
    /// Events are sent in coordinates offset by aX and aY from the window.
    ///
    /// Cannot be accessed from unprivileged context (not content-accessible)
    /// Will throw a DOM security error if called without chrome privileges.
    ///
    /// The event is dispatched via the toplevel window, so it could go to any
    /// window under the toplevel window, in some cases it could never reach this
    /// window at all.
    ///
    /// @param aType event type
    /// @param xs array of offsets in CSS pixels for each touch to be sent
    /// @param ys array of offsets in CSS pixels for each touch to be sent
    /// @param rxs array of radii in CSS pixels for each touch to be sent
    /// @param rys array of radii in CSS pixels for each touch to be sent
    /// @param rotationAngles array of angles in degrees for each touch to be sent
    /// @param forces array of forces (floats from 0 to 1) for each touch to be sent
    /// @param count number of touches in this set
    /// @param aModifiers modifiers pressed, using constants defined as MODIFIER_*
    /// @param aIgnoreRootScrollFrame whether the event should ignore viewport bounds
    /// during dispatch
    ///
    /// returns true if the page called prevent default on this touch event
    /// </summary>
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    bool SendTouchEvent([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalType = "Gecko.CustomMarshalers.AStringMarshaler")] nsAStringBase aType, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=8)] uint[] aIdentifiers, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=8)] int[] aXs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=8)] int[] aYs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=8)] uint[] aRxs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=8)] uint[] aRys, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=8)] float[] aRotationAngles, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=8)] float[] aForces, uint count, int aModifiers, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] bool aIgnoreRootScrollFrame);
```

And then , I test my method like that :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uint[] ident ={1};
    int[] ax={200};
    int[] ay={200};
    uint[] rx ={2};
    uint[] ry ={2};
    float[] ro ={20};
    float[] force={(float)0.8};
    bool r = browser.Window.WindowUtils.SendTouchEvent("touchstart", ident, ax, ay, rx, ry, ro, force, (uint)1, 0, true);
    Application.DoEvents();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        ay[0]+=10;
        r = browser.Window.WindowUtils.SendTouchEvent("touchmove", ident, ax, ay, rx, ry, ro, force, (uint)1, 0, true);
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(10);
     }
     r = browser.Window.WindowUtils.SendTouchEvent("touchend", ident, ax, ay, rx, ry, ro, force, (uint)1, 0, true); 
 }
```

But, it always returns false;Could Anyone help me? Thanks in advance.